# sveltejs function does not update unless i pass in an a variable

Tags: svelte

this code doesnt work

```
<script>
    import '../app.css';
    let inputField = '';
    function evaluateInput() {
        let result;
        try {
            result = eval(inputField);
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
            result = 'invalid input';
            return result;
        }
    }
</script>


<h1 >
    <input bind:value={inputField} /> = {evaluateInput()}
</h1>
```

but for some reason it does work when i add this

```
<script>
    import '../app.css';
    let inputField = '';
    function evaluateInput() {
        let result;
        try {
            result = eval(inputField);
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
            result = 'invalid input';
            return result;
        }
    }
</script>


<h1 >
    <input bind:value={inputField} /> = {evaluateInput(inputField)}
</h1>
```

i wanted it to run the eval function each time `inputField` changes but it just sits there and does nothing unless i pass in `inputField` as an argument to the function and i have no idea what causes this

Comment: (In Svelte 5 this sort of logic will automatically work because dependencies are tracked at runtime through execution, so the function boundary no longer matters for reactivity.)